# React component gives JSX error if the component file is not in same directory as node_modules/webpack.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I got the following files.

**st-product-detail.js**

```js
import React                from 'react';
import { render }           from "react-dom";

export default class STProductDetail extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <h1>React Component</h1>
        );
    }
}

render(<STProductDetail />, document.getElementById('st-product-detail-app'));
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./st-product-detail.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path  = require("path");

const entryFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'st-product-detail/st-product-detail.js')
// const entryFile = path.join(__dirname, 'st-product-detail.js')

const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'js')

// const modulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'st-product-detail')
const modulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'st-product-detail')

console.log('entryFile  ', entryFile)
console.log('modulesPath', modulesPath)
console.log('outputPath ', outputPath)

module.exports = {

    entry   :   entryFile,
    output  :   {
                    path        : outputPath,
                    filename    : 'st-product-detail.min.js'
                },
    mode    : process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",

    resolve :   {
                    roots: [__dirname, modulesPath],
                    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
                    modules :   [
                                    modulesPath,
                                    path.resolve(__dirname), "node_modules"
                                ],
                    alias   :   {
                                    product : modulesPath,
                                },
                },

    module  :   {
                    rules: [
                                {
                                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                                    use:  "babel-loader"

                                },
                    ],
                },

};
```

**.babelrc**

```json
{
    "presets"   :   [
                        "@babel/env",
                        "@babel/react"
                    ],

    "plugins"   :   [
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
                    ]
}
```

**Structure**

```
- js
    - st-product-detail.min.js #output file
- src
    - js
        - components
        - node
             - node_modules
             - .babelrc
             - package.json
             - webpack.config.js
        - st-product-detail
            - st-product-detail.js
```

The problem is that, since `st-product-detail/st-product-detail.js` is not in the same path as `node_modules` / `webpack.config.js` I am getting the following error.

```js
ERROR in ../st-product-detail/st-product-detail.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /<PATH>/st-product-detail/src/js/st-product-detail/st-product-detail.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (22:13):

  20 |     {
  21 |         return(
> 22 |             <h1>React Component</h1>
     |             ^
  23 |         );
  24 |     }
  25 | }

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

When I copy `st-product-detail.js` into `node` folder and execute `npm run webpack` it compiles just fine.

Did I miss anything in the config files which causes this?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after some digging I think I've gotten it.

I deleted `.babelrc` file and created a new one named `babel.config.js` (new way of config) with the following content

```js
module.exports = {
    presets  : ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
}
```

So far it seems working fine. I'll keep posting.